# Multiple Authentication Provider in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, authentication

In my SpringBoot application, I am trying to implement two different authorizations for two different areas.

Area 1 [API]: 
/api/**

Area 2 [Admin]:
/admin/**

The Area 1 [API] is the API part of my application where I have implemented JWT Authentication. Every request that starts with `/api` will require an Authorization header containing jwt token.

The Area 2 [Admin]: is the admin area. Where I would like to log in with an URL from the browser, For example (/admin/login). I would like to have my username and password saved in the application.properties and for any URL that starts with `/admin`, I want the user to be authenticated (Session-based). I want to apply in-memory authentication in that case. I am looking for ideas to implement these two different authentications for two different areas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.authorizeRequests()` method to configure endpoints for that security configuration file.

In `void configure(HttpSecurity http)` method in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` or `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` file you can use like

```html
    http
    .antMatcher("/api/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
    ...
```

Then spring security will start authorizing requests starting with `/api` path.
If added it in `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` spring oauth2 will start authorizing from there. To configure web security for an endpoint like `/admin`, in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```html
http
    .antMatcher("/admin/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
    ...
```

Comment: Can't fully understand the answer